# GetClipboardData always returns NULL

Tags: vba, clipboard, api

I have the following code:

```
Public Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub test()
Dim wat As String

OpenClipboard (0&)
wat = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
MsgBox wat
CloseClipboard

End Sub
```

This always returns 0 (NULL) in the msgbox. Could somone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: I would presume the problem is your call to `OpenClipboard`, what boolean value does it return?  Edit your question to include this vital information

Comment: @Ramhound how would I know that (in the sense how do I verify that)?

Comment: The same way you verified the other method was returning 0.  Use a variable to capture the return value.

Comment: @Ramhound doesn't seem to be the brightest of days for me. Indeed I can confirm that the Boolean is 1.

Comment: @Ramhound I think the code does actually work, it just doesn't return what I would expect it to. If the clipboard is empty, it returns 0, if it is not empty it returns a seemingly random number of integers (e.g. "*" returns 791549112). I would have expected it does return the actual copied text.

Comment: `GetClipboardData` returns a handle to the object.  It does not contain the contents of the clipboard, for obvious reasons, the object might not be text.  `OpenClipboard` returns a nonzero function if it successful.  You can get the reason, it's 0, by using `GetLastError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetClipboardData will deliver a handle to the global memory block.
You will have to lock this block and retrieve the String from there.

Based on [windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard) a quick an dirty example based on your question:

```
Public Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
Public Const CF_TEXT = 1
Public Const MAXSIZE = 4096






Sub test()
Dim wat As String
Dim hClipMemory As Long
Dim lpClipMemory As Long
Dim Dummy As Long
If OpenClipboard(0&) <> 0 Then    
  hClipMemory = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
  If Not IsNull(hClipMemory) Then
    lpClipMemory = GlobalLock(hClipMemory)
    If Not IsNull(lpClipMemory) Then
        wat = Space$(MAXSIZE)
        Dummy = lstrcpy(wat, lpClipMemory)
        GlobalUnlock (hClipMemory)
    End If
  End If      
  MsgBox wat
CloseClipboard
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @bummi. I am very new to calling the user32 and kernel32 libraries, consequently it seems I fully failed to understand how this code should have been executed. I awarded you the solution as what you posted actually does do what I would have wanted it to do. And thank you for the link I will examine the full code and documentation to get a better understanding of what is actually going on.